# batch script to automate button click

Tags: batch-file

I am supposed to create a batch file which automatically installs any software ,say nodejs on client machine.The problem that i am having is i can start the installation process through my script but i cant make the script to automatically click the buttons like "next","finish" etc.

```
msiexec /a "<D:\BAtch file\node-v8.9.4-x64.msi>" /qb TARGETDIR="C:\Node.js"
```

This is for initializing the node installer on windows.

Is there any way i can do this in a batch script?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps just use `msiexec /?` to see the help.

```
msiexec /qn /l* nodejs.log /i node-v8.9.4-x64.msi
```

You are using `/qb` where `b` is **b**asic UI, however you want **n**o UI, therefore use `/qn`

Some extract from `/?`

```
/q[n|b|r|f]
    Sets user interface level
    n - No UI
    b - Basic UI
    r - Reduced UI
    f - Full UI (default)
```